# getting error when i paste the long query in the variable (ASP.NET MVC RAZOR)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

can i ask the format solution for this long script? I'am new here in asp because it's different in PHP when declaring long script, in PHP just copy and paste then it will be okay. but in ASP. The script must be in long line.

Sample script

```
    String sql = "SELECT
   timesheet.date,

  MAX(CASE
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter = 1
    then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =1 then 'SICK LEAVE'
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =1  then 'VACATION LEAVE'
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =1  then log
    END) as note1,


  MAX(case
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter =2
  then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =2 then 'SICK LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =2 then 'VACATION LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =2 then log
  else ''
  end) as note2,

  MAX(case
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter =3
  then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =3 then 'SICK LEAVE'
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =3 then 'VACATION LEAVE'
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =3  then log
  else ''
  end) as note3,

  MAX(case
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter =4
  then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =4  then 'SICK LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =4  then 'VACATION LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =4  then log
  else ''
  end) as note4


FROM timesheet

LEFT JOIN schedules ON timesheet.empid = schedules.empid

WHERE timesheet.empid='40' and YEAR(timesheet.date) = 2017

AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = 5

AND timesheet.date <= CURDATE()

AND timeStatus='OK'

GROUP BY timesheet.date,timesheet.empid "
```

to solve the problem asp.net requirements 
sample script is this

SELECT timeshet.date, MAX(CASE WHEN timein1 =8 and note = 'HOLIDAY' and counter = 1 etc etc etc............

thanks guys..

Comment: You can use concatenation operator **+**.

Comment: Create a store procedure for it, then you only need to execute that store procedure. Much cleaner.

Comment: Use literal string `String sql = @"SELECT ..."` to wrap up your query in multiple lines. But I prefer creating a stored procedure & calling that from the ORM/`SqlConnection`.

Comment: We used in our team Mysql connection how is it?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto why don't you post your solution as an answer? I would do it even if answer is short obvious

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 common ways to concatenate long strings:

1. Using [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) (marked with `@` sign before double quotes).
   Example:

   ```
   String sql = @"SELECT timesheet.date, MAX(CASE WHEN timein1 = 8 
                  and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter = 1 ...";
   ```
2. Using [concatenation operator (+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings) for every lines.
   Example:

   ```
   String sql = "SELECT timesheet.date, MAX(CASE WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter = 1 ..." + 
                ... +
                "GROUP BY timesheet.date,timesheet.empid";
   ```
3. Using [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for multiple commands.
   Example:

   ```
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("SELECT timesheet.date,");
   sb.Append("MAX(CASE WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter = 1 ..."); 
   // other append methods

   String sql = sb.ToString();
   ```

The verbatim string method is the most efficient of all, since it only delimited by another double quotes (only double quote signs needs to be escaped, e.g. `""` for `"`).

If you want to perform string concatenation with other variable values, you need to use `String.Format` combined with verbatim string & composite formatting like this:

```
String sql = String.Format(@"SELECT ... 
                            FROM timesheet LEFT JOIN schedules ON timesheet.empid = schedules.empid
                            WHERE timesheet.empid='40' AND YEAR(timesheet.date) = {0} 
                            AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = {1} 
                            AND timesheet.date <= CURDATE() 
                            AND timeStatus='OK' 
                            GROUP BY timesheet.date,timesheet.empid", List, List_month);
```

NB: If you have long query string like that, I prefer to create a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) like this:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER = [definer_name] PROCEDURE [procedure_name]
-- [parameters if any]
BEGIN 
    SELECT timesheet.date, MAX(CASE WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter = 1 ...
END;
```

And then invoke the procedure by [MySQL database connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html):

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("[MySQL_connection_string]"))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand("[procedure_name]", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // add parameters here

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // reading data from database
            }

            // other stuff
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle exceptions here
    }
}
```

Comment: AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = ' " + List_month + "' 

                AND timesheet.date <= CURDATE()

                AND timeStatus='OK'                                                                      it says I need to used newline constant. how to that in  + List_month  +

Comment: Use `String.Format(@"SELECT ... AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = '{0}' AND ...", List_month)`. If you using string concatenation from other variables, use `String.Format` together with verbatim string literal & [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) to join them in one string.

Comment: can i have the correct code for that. 
                WHERE timesheet.empid='40' and YEAR(timesheet.date) = + List +

                AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = + List_month  +

Comment: @SirGeorgeMuncal You can have more than one composite formatting, but *ensure they're lined in proper order*, e.g. `String.Format(@"SELECT ... and YEAR(timesheet.date) = {0} AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = {1} AND ...", List, List_month)`. I hope you're understand from the MSDN reference given above.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use @ like mentioned below

```
String sql = @"SELECT
   timesheet.date,

  MAX(CASE
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter = 1
    then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =1 then 'SICK LEAVE'
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =1  then 'VACATION LEAVE'
    WHEN timein1 = 8 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =1  then log
    END) as note1,


  MAX(case
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter =2
  then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =2 then 'SICK LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =2 then 'VACATION LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout1 = 12 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =2 then log
  else ''
  end) as note2,

  MAX(case
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter =3
  then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =3 then 'SICK LEAVE'
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =3 then 'VACATION LEAVE'
  WHEN timein2 = 13 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =3  then log
  else ''
  end) as note3,

  MAX(case
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='HOLIDAY' and counter =4
  then (SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE timesheet.date = holidays.date)
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='SICK LEAVE' and counter =4  then 'SICK LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='VACATION LEAVE' and counter =4  then 'VACATION LEAVE'
  WHEN timeout2 = 17 and note ='REGULAR LOGGED' and counter =4  then log
  else ''
  end) as note4


FROM timesheet

LEFT JOIN schedules ON timesheet.empid = schedules.empid

WHERE timesheet.empid='40' and YEAR(timesheet.date) = 2017

AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = 5

AND timesheet.date <= CURDATE()

AND timeStatus='OK'

GROUP BY timesheet.date,timesheet.empid "
```